# How to get actual column names based on entity variable names?

Tags: java, spring-boot, entity

I want to get actual column name that is in db from entity variable names.

Eg:

i have an entity as below,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="test_detail",schema = "test")
public class Test {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(name = "id")
private Long id;

@Column(name="test_status")
private Boolean testStatus;

@Column(name="test_status1")
    private Boolean testStatus1;
    }
```

I had populated this entity using springboot repository get/find calls.

```
Test t = repository.findById(1l);
```

I have a list L which contains the names of the colums as

> ['id','test_status']

i need to get the values of column names that are mentioned in the list L.In this case i dont need values present in testStatus1.

How do i do that?

or

Is there any way to get only the values for the columns mentioned in the list directly?

There are few criteria that need to be met:

- Criteria 1 : should not use Namedqueries/@Query annotations
- Criteria 2 : the columns in the List L might vary from request to request. it is generated dynamically.Sometimes all the columns are listed sometimes just one or two columns listed.

Comment: How to get actual column names based on entity variable names? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921451/get-column-name-in-jpa?lq=1

Comment: JPA/EclipseLink - Retrieve Columns Names - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3657968/jpa-eclipselink-retrieve-columns-names/25520204#25520204

Comment: How to get Column names of JPA entity -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46335682/how-to-get-column-names-of-jpa-entity