# How to get the column Name String of an Entity class in Java/Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a Entity Class:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "MyTasks", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"id"})
    public class MyTasks {
      @Id
      @Column(name = "id")
      private Integer id;

      @Column(name = "task_name")
      private String task_name;

      @Column(name = "task_data")
      private String task_data;
    }
```

Say, I have an instance of an entity by calling new MyTasks();
How can I get all the Column Names of this entity class, say in an array String[]?

Comment: 2 approaches: 1. *Code* the column names into a static (final) String[], and use them. 2. Use reflection + `AbstractEntityPersister` (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46337170/592355))

Comment: Try this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46335682/how-to-get-column-names-of-jpa-entity

Answer (score 0):

Use reflection and pass the method name you want the column for. For Example:

```
    ArrayList<String> columnNames = new ArrayList<>();
    Method[] methods = someObjectOrClass.getMethods();
    for (Method method : methods) {
        // get the @Column annotation for the class
        Column col = method.getAnnotation(Column.class);
        if (col != null) {
            columnNames.add(method.getAnnotation(Column.class).name());
        }
    }
    columnNames.toArray();
```